# Swift 3, Xcode 8- Test case project compilation errors

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, cedar-bdd, quick-nimble

I have got a project from a company to develop where the original developers left.
Project details:

- carthage for dependancy management
- Pivotal Cedar, Quick and Nimble for test case project

The project was developed in Swift 2.0.
I converted the project to swift 3 in Xcode 8. The main target (main app) is converted properly and is getting compiled and run on the device.
But the Test case target has compilation errors.
Could't figure out the problem.
Please help[image]

```
import Foundation

protocol SessionManager {
    var token: String? { get set }
    var selectedContract: String? { get set }
    var contracts: [String] { get set }
}

class LoginSessionManager: SessionManager {
    var token: String?
    var selectedContract: String?
    var contracts: [String] = []
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post some code so we can see what's going on. Chances are that Xcode didn't properly convert the test target and you'll need to make some updates manually.

Comment: Added code, please check